# Get value of slider in pixels

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a custom range slider. Everything works well besides for when I try getting the current value in pixels.

Here's the relevant code: (In `function sliderMove` line 30)

```
cursorPosition = ((e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX) || e.clientX) - startPoint.left;
rangePosition = clamp(cursorPosition, _sliderPositions.rangeStart, _sliderPositions.rangeEnd);
value = percentToPixel((rangePosition / _sliderPositions.currentValue) * 100, 0, 500);

function percentToPixel(percent, min, max) {
    if (typeof max === 'undefined') return;
    return ((percent / 100) * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

`value` doesn't give the correct result. It's supposed to be between 0 - 500, but it gives 1+ - 500+ depending on the size of the window. (If you resize the window, then reload, and try the slider again, you will see it gives a different min and max number for value.)

#### JSFiddle

```js
console.clear();

function RangeSlider( /** DOM Elem */ parentElem) {
  var wrapperElem = document.getElementsByClassName('wrapperElem')[0],
    slider = document.getElementsByClassName('slider')[0],
    sliderRange = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderRange')[0],
    sliderCursor = document.getElementsByClassName('sliderCursor')[0],
    output = document.getElementById('output'),
    myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');

  var sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth,
    cursorRadius = sliderCursor.offsetHeight / 2,
    startPoint,
    currentTarget,
    value = 0,
    _sliderPositions = {},
    borderWidth = 1;

  startPoint = getOrigin(wrapperElem.children[0]);
  sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;


  function sliderDown(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
    sliderMove(e);
  }

  function sliderMove(e) {
    var rangePosition = 0;
    var cursorPosition = 0;
    reconfigVars();
    if (typeof e === 'object') {
      cursorPosition = ((e.touches && e.touches[0].clientX) || e.clientX) - startPoint.left;
    } else {
      cursorPosition = pixelToPercent(value, 0, 500) / 100 * sliderDimention;
    }
    //console.log(cursorPosition);

    rangePosition = clamp(cursorPosition, _sliderPositions.rangeStart, _sliderPositions.rangeEnd);
    cursorPosition = clamp(cursorPosition - cursorRadius, _sliderPositions.cursorStart, _sliderPositions.cursorEnd);

    sliderCursor.style.transform = 'translateX(' + cursorPosition + 'px)';
    sliderRange.style.transform = 'scaleX(' + rangePosition + ')';

    if (typeof e === 'object') {
      value = percentToPixel((rangePosition / _sliderPositions.currentValue) * 100, 0, 500);
    }
    output.innerHTML = value;

  }


  function reconfigVars() {
    _sliderPositions.rangeStart = borderWidth * 2;
    _sliderPositions.rangeEnd = sliderDimention - borderWidth * 2
    _sliderPositions.cursorStart = startPoint.left - cursorRadius + borderWidth * 2;
    _sliderPositions.cursorEnd = sliderDimention - borderWidth * 2 - cursorRadius * 2;
    _sliderPositions.currentValue = sliderDimention - borderWidth * 2 - startPoint.left - cursorRadius;
  }

  myButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    sliderMove(500);
    value = 500;
  });






  function mouseUpEvents() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', sliderMove);
  }
  wrapperElem.addEventListener('mousedown', sliderDown);
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUpEvents);
}



var sliderTest = document.getElementById('sliderTest');
var test = new RangeSlider(sliderTest);







function getOrigin(elm) {
  var box = (elm.getBoundingClientRect) ? elm.getBoundingClientRect() : {
      top: 0,
      left: 0
    },
    doc = elm && elm.ownerDocument,
    body = doc.body,
    win = doc.defaultView || doc.parentWindow || window,
    docElem = doc.documentElement || body.parentNode,
    clientTop = docElem.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0, // border on html or body or both
    clientLeft = docElem.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

  return {
    left: box.left + (win.pageXOffset || docElem.scrollLeft) - clientLeft,
    top: box.top + (win.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop) - clientTop
  };
}

function clamp(val, moreThan, lessThan) {
  if (typeof lessThan === 'undefined') lessThan = 1;
  if (typeof moreThan === 'undefined') moreThan = 0;
  return Math.min(lessThan, Math.max(moreThan, val));
}

function pixelToPercent(pixel, min, max) {
  if (typeof max === 'undefined') return;
  return ((pixel - min) / (max - min)) * 100;
}

function percentToPixel(percent, min, max) {
  if (typeof max === 'undefined') return;
  return ((percent / 100) * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

```css
.wrapperElem {
  height: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex;
}
.slider {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 62px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: relative;
}
.sliderCursor {
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
.sliderRange {
  background-color: green;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: left;
}
#output {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperElem">
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="sliderRange"></div>
    <div class="sliderCursor"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="output"></div>
<button id="myButton">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: It's a little unclear if `value` is meant to be the value of the slider or its width in pixels? From the code as it is now, `value` will be the value of the slider, which ranges from 0 - 500 (supposed to anyway, the issue notwithstanding), regardless of the size of the window. Resizing the window after the fact does not refresh the slider dimensions in your script, which is a part of the problem as well.

Comment: @XerenNarcy `value` is supposed to be the value of the slider 0 - 500. Part of the problem was, that when you resize the window, then rerun the code, the value ranges will show different amounts. What I want it to be, is 0 - 500

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offset from 0 - 500 -> 1 - 514 (for example) is because the mouse position on the slider background is used to determine the value, rather than the xoffset of the slider cursor. The excess values are going to be proportional to `14 * 500 / sliderwidth` on the 500 end, and `500 / sliderwidth` on the 0 end.

This however does not give you the value in pixels: because you're obtaining a percentage of the slider's value, you've calculated just that - how much of it is filled. You're then scaling it to the slider's value range (0 - 500). If you need the value in pixels, *don't* take a percentage or you lose unit information and have to get it back by scaling against the silder's dimensions.

There are 3 areas involved in where the mouse *could be* and your value-obtaining code needs to factor that into account:

1. area between leftmost part of the slider and the center of the slider cursor when the cursor is at its leftmost position - in pixels: 0px to 7px (half of your cursor's width).
2. as above, but with rightmost. in pixels: (sliderwidth-7) px to sliderwidth px.
3. the area in-between: 7px - (sliderwidth-7)px

To correctly get 0 - 500 (slider *value* not left-offset in px) you need to measure a percentage of area #3, clamping the mouse position against the slider to those same values. In other words, you need to use `cursorPosition` rather than `rangePosition`, but your percentage is going to be against the size of area #3 rather than the width of the slider in full.

Furthermore, the window-resizing issues are because of this snippet not running within `reconfigVars()`:

```
  sliderDimention = slider.offsetWidth;
```

At the least element dimensions and positions could change due to resizing, it should go into a `resize` event which does this and then also calls `reconfigVars()` and any other events that update the slider based on its dimensions.

If there's more to it I'll update my answer but I think that's all that needs to be adjusted.

---

The above details aside... The simplest change I can make to get it working is this:

```
if (typeof e === 'object') {
    value = percentToPixel( (
      (sliderPosition - _sliderPositions.cursorStart) / (_sliderPositions.cursorEnd - _sliderPositions.cursorStart)
    ) * 100, 0, 500);
}
```

This is taking into account the first and third paragraphs, the second paragraph is more to note if you had wanted a pixel readout.

---

#### First paragraph explained

If you imagine the slider layout in its structural form, you have these positions to worry about:

```
/-------------------------------------\
|  (cursor-start)       (cursor-end)  |
\-------------------------------------/
        slider r-offset - border*2 = ^
 cursor r-most extent = ^
   ^ = cursor left-most extent
 ^ = slider offset + border
```

The calculation I've modified now calculates the % that the cursor position makes from the left-most extent to the r-most extent. In other words the full range of motion for the cursor is what the % divisor should be, and the cursor position relative to the start of that range of motion is what should be the numerator. Hopefully that makes sense..

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! It is a bit complicating though, and I don't completely understand the first paragraph, and because the second paragraph is linked to the first one, I don't understand the second paragraph either. Can you please explain in more detail the first paragraph? Thanks!

Comment: @Jessica no worries, I've updated my answer to explain that in more detail with a (poorly done) visual representation of what's been calculated in place of your original code.

Comment: Why does `_sliderPosition.currentValue` subtract `borderWidth * 2` two times? When assigning `cursorPosition`, is there a way to do `(_sliderPositions.currentValue - borderWidth * 2)` in the `reconfig function`?

Comment: @Jessica because I didn't read into it too much, just used the closest values that had the correct computation :) on closer inspection it ought to be `(_sliderPositions.cursorEnd - _sliderPositions.cursorStart)` rather than using `currentValue`. If you want to do it all in `reconfig` you also need to move into there `cursorPosition`, then `(sliderPosition - _sliderPositions.cursorStart) / (_sliderPositions.cursorEnd - _sliderPositions.cursorStart)` can be computed for the slider value (`currentValue`).